# Installing programs from source won't work

Tags: make

I've tried to install three things from source now, but after I close Terminal (Mac), they seem to 'disappear' and I can't use the commands that worked before.

The first was [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). I cloned the git repo into my Downloads folder, and followed the commands

```
./configure
make
make install
```

after which `node` worked. After closing and reopening `node` returns `-bash: node: command not found`.

The second was [npm](http://npmjs.org/), which never worked, no matter which way I installed it. First I tried the one-liner: `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh` but that didn't work, and cloning the git repo and `sudo make install` didn't work either.

The third was [CoffeeScript.js](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) which, after downloading, and compiling, didn't work either. Obviously installing it via `npm` wouldn't work either!

Any help would be ***GREATLY*** appreciated as I may be making some silly mistake.

Fred

Comment: Given the accepted answer and the age of this question, it serves absolutely no useful information for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it again and it worked, so I have no idea what went wrong.